# rabbitmq monitoring master node in the cluster configuration

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, high-availability

is there a way to understand who is the master node in the cluster High Availability configuration?

is it possibile to do this using the monitoring tool ?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to understand who is the master node in the cluster
> High Availability configuration?

I assume you mean "queue master", i.e. the node that is running the actual queue. This information can be shown by running `rabbitmqctl list_queues name pid` which will show the name of the master node in the `pid` column. Or, you can query the information using the [HTTP API](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.9/priv/www/api/index.html)

```
$ curl -4su guest:guest localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F | jq '.[] | "\(.name) \(.node)"'
"amq.gen-S-CMD0E2NPXabpIOGdvDQg rabbit@localhost"
"test rabbit@localhost"
```